# A tablist/tab accessibility, is it normal for the screen readers to see square bracket?

Tags: html, wai-aria, screen-readers

I want to know if it is normal for screen readers to read:

'Sports [] selected expanded tab, 1 of 2'

```
<div role="tablist">
     <a role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-selected="false">Sports</a>
     <a role="tab" aria-expanded="true" aria-selected="true">News</a>
</div>
```

I am not very expert in accessibility, I want to know your opinions.

Answer (score 0):

You will find that different screen readers read things, well, differently.  All you have to worry about is setting the proper roles and attributes, which you're doing in your small sample.  VoiceOver (on the Mac and iOS devices), NVDA (on the PC), and JAWS (on the PC) will all read variations of what you're hearing.  Some might say "1 of 2" and others will leave that out (the latter of which I find personally annoying).  Some might say 'expanded' before 'selected'.

As a side note, just because you have something expanded, it doesn't necessarily mean it's selected.  I know your example was just a small snippet for demo purposes, but I wanted to point it out.

Comment: Hmm, I think I glossed right over your "square bracket" comment.  Are you hearing "left bracket, right bracket" with your small example?  That would be odd.

Comment: I dont know how that bracket appeared, it just came as it is on the VoiceOver on MAC

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your CSS? I'm guessing that you have some CSS content. If this content is a glyph, you will hear different things based on the screen reader. If the code is in one of the [private use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas) areas, then there is no definition for that.

In the code sample I provided below, the CSS content is "\E70D". The "E7" is in the Private Use Area of UTF-16. These sometimes are read by screen readers as "blank". In your case, the output of the screen reader doesn't know what the character is, so you get a little rectangle.

```css
[role="tab"]::before{
  content:"\E70D";
}
```

```html
<div role="tablist">
     <a role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-selected="false">Sports</a>
     <a role="tab" aria-expanded="true" aria-selected="true">News</a>
</div>
```